# Show posts and image in same div

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have featured images shown for different posts of same category in a page in a specific div. I need to show the whole post related to this image in the same page in another div. I know i must use JavaScript in this. But i need some reference which i can use for this. Can anyone help me with this? I am using the following code to show the images

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Meet The Team Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id = "meet_posts" class = "narrowcolumn">
<?php 
     $recent = new WP_Query("cat=6&orderby=title&order=ASC"); 
     while( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post();
     $desc_values = get_post_custom_values("description");

?>
<div id="meetteam_featured_image">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="title">
     <?php
          if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
              the_post_thumbnail();
          }
     ?>
     </a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a little difficult to determine what you're asking. You have an image in one div and you want to display some text related to that image in another div. Is that right?

Comment: Yes.. I have the featured image of a post showing on one div. I want to show the content of that post in another div on same page. http://congruentsolutions.com/?page_id=155 . See this page for example. you can see what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your above code with this following code :

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Meet The Team Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="meet_posts" class="narrowcolumn">
<?php 
$recent = new WP_Query("cat=6&orderby=title&order=ASC"); 
while($recent->have_posts()):$recent->the_post();
$desc_values = get_post_custom_values("description");

?>
<div id="meetteam_featured_image" class="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="title">
 <?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  { 
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
?>
</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile ?>
<div id="image-post-info"></div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Add this following code in functions.php file :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxified_function', 'ajaxified_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxified_function', 'ajaxified_function' );
function ajaxified_function() {   
$temp = get_post($_POST['post_id']);
echo $temp->post_title.'<br/><br/>'.$temp->post_content;   
die();
}
```

Add this following code in your custom js file :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){       

 jQuery('#meetteam_featured_image a').on('click',function(event){         
 event.preventDefault();

 var post_id = jQuery(this).parent().attr('class');            
 jQuery.ajax({  
   type: "POST",                  
   url:  'http://www.yoursitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
   data: 'action=ajaxified_function&post_id='+post_id,    
   success: function (msg) {                                        
      jQuery('#image-post-info').html(msg);
  },
  error: function () {                  
    alert('Error');                    
   }  
    });           
  });       
});
```

Add custom js file by including following code in functions.php file :

```
function add_custom_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/custom-     scripts.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_scripts' );
```

Hope this will help....!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id = "meet_posts" class = "narrowcolumn">
<?php 
     $recent = new WP_Query("cat=6&orderby=title&order=ASC"); 
     while( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post();
     $desc_values = get_post_custom_values("description");

?>  
</div><!--close first div-->

<div id="meetteam_featured_image">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="title">
     <?php
          if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
              the_post_thumbnail();
          }
     ?>
     </a>
</div><!--close second div-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This one gives just the values in the custom field. I need the whole post in another div in same page. Please refer http://congruentsolutions.com/?page_id=155  to understand what i really want..

Comment: Not my problem you asked the question poorly, happy trails

Comment: In that webpage it is a div within a div...Postcontent within sitecontent...that is all